# What are some simple examples illustrating the definition of "cover"

Tags: general-topology

In my class the word "cover" is used very informally such as this set covers another set (this is for a class in PDE not topology by the way).

Can someone provide a trivial example of cover to get the point across?

Say if I want a set to cover the real line, what do I mean by set? Can I cover a line segment? Can the set be points?

Comment: At least in the context of topology (in analysis as well), you can have a collection of sets $A_{\alpha}$ (this can be finite or infinite) that cover a set $B$. In other words, $B \subset \bigcup_{\alpha} A_{\alpha}$.

Comment: http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Covering_space for "covering space" - important in topology, and http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Covering for the general "covering of a set"

Comment: I google-image-searched "open cover" and [this popped up](https://simomaths.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/compact_spaces.png).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take some space $X$. A *cover* for $X$ is a bunch of sets, say $U_1, U_2, ...$ so that $X \subseteq U_1 \cup U_2 \cup ...$ (That is, $X$ is contained in the union of $U_1, U_2, ...$)

In layperson terms, a *cover* for a set $X$ is a **bunch of sets** so that $X$ is completely contained in that **bunch of sets**.

*Other cool things:*

We could also define an ***open*** cover. An open cover is the exact same thing as a cover, except each $U_1, U_2, ...$ is *open*.

We could also define a ***finite*** cover. A finite cover is simply a cover  $U_1, U_2, ..., U_n$ with a finite number of $U_i$'s.

We could also define a ***sub***cover. A subcover is simply a cover that is contained within another cover. So say $U_1, U_2, U_3$ covers $X$. But let's say, it happens to be the case that, hey, $U_1, U_2$ *also* covers $X$. Well, then $U_1, U_2$ is a *subcover* of $U_1, U_2, U_3$. They are both perfectly valid covers--it just so happens that one is contained in the other.

The idea of a cover gives rise to *compactness*, which is can be a very powerful mathematical concept. A space $X$ is compact if, for every **open cover** (remember, an open cover is a bunch of sets that are each open, so that $X$ is contained in that bunch of sets), we can find a **finite subcover** (so we can find a cover *within* that **open cover** that is finite). So, **for every** bunch of open sets that you can find that covers $X$...if I can take that bunch of open sets, dwindle it down to all but a *finite* bunch of open sets that still covers $X$, then $X$ is compact.

Comment: That's awesome...you are better than Euler at topology! :)

Comment: Hah! I really like general topology, but in reality, I suck at it. But I think that's the case with any branch of math...I like 'em, but I ain't too good at 'em. Truth is I am still learning about this stuff, just as you are.

Comment: Jesse Madnick thanks for finding that silly mistake.

@FemaleTank I didn't really address the last line in your question. In general topology, we don't really make a distinction between a number "line" or a set of numbers. The real number line is just an easy way to visualize the *set* of real numbers. Not all sets can be arranged on a line, though. It only works because the real numbers have ordering ($2$ is bigger than $1$).

Comment: I also added a simple example.

Comment: Your example is very wrong: $\{ 1/2 \}$ is not open in the standard topology, and your given cover is finite. The usual infinite cover here is $\{ (1/n,1-1/n) : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ or similar.

Comment: ...which supports my claim that i suck at topology  thanks for pointing that out. i wasn't thinking properly--mainly obvious from the fact that my cover was very finite...hah!

Answer (score 4):

**Definition**. $X$ be a topological space, $A \subseteq X$ a subspace (not necessarily a strict one). An open cover of $A$ in $X$ is a collection of open sets $\{\mathcal{U}_i\}$ in $X$ such that $A \subseteq \bigcup_i \mathcal{U}_i$.

**Geometric meaning**. An open cover of $A$ is a collection of (possibly overlapping) open sets in $X$ which, after looking at their union globally, contains $A$ inside. This where the terminology "cover" comes from : you're using small, simple open sets to fill up a rather complicated-to-inspect subspace $A$ of $X$.

As an example, consider the circle $S^1 = \{z : |z| = 1\}$ embedded in $\Bbb C$. Consider the collection of open sets $\{\mathcal{U}_i\}$ where $\mathcal{U}_i$ are "thickened" arcs of the circle $S^1$. This covers $S^1$.

**Importance**. Open covers are not necessarily always "nice". For example, consider the open cover $\{(1/n, 1)_{n \in \Bbb N}\}$ of the interval $(0, 1)$. So, you might think that it's just a technical term and of no particular use. However, you're just missing the point.

Open covers are a language to shift from the topological point-of-view to a combinatoric point-of-view. More precisely, instead of inspecting properties of a topological space $X$ by hand, one tries to inspect combinatorial properties of the open covers of $X$, which sometimes turns out to be a very easy thing to do due to having less structure.

For example, consider $(0, 1) \subset \Bbb R^2$. This is most certainly not homeomorphic to, say, $[0, 1]$. An obvious argument is that the former is something "large" (homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$), while the latter is "small". The correct analytic formalization of this idea is sequential compactness, i.e., that every infinite sequence has a convergent subsequence. One can use some analysis to show that $[0, 1]$ is sequentially compact while $(0, 1)$  is not. However,

$\text{Fact}$ : In good spaces, sequential compactness is equivalent to the property "every countable cover has a finite subcover".

A complete characterization of good spaces is a bit complicated, but metric spaces are examples of such spaces. In any case, note that the open cover of $(0, 1)$ produced in the answer above has no finite subcover, while every open cover of $[0, 1]$ has a finite subcover (try proving this!). Thus, we have just used a combinatorial property of open covers to get back analytic properties of the total space. In particular, the property of open covers I have mentioned above is called (countable) compactness of topological spaces.

Another cool thing about open covers is the Lebesgue covering lemma, which states that given a compact metric space with an open cover, there is a positive real number $\epsilon$ such that each open set of diameter at most $\epsilon$ fits inside an open set in the cover. This is a very nice theorem, which in turn is used to prove the fact I have mentioned above. This also has interesting applications in algebraic topology (for example, in the proof of excision theorem for singular homology).

Answer (score 2):

For the interval $[0,6]$ the set of $\{B_1(0),B_1(1),B_1(2),B_1(3),B_1(4),B_1(5),B_1(6)\}$
is a cover, where $B_\epsilon(x)$ is the open ball of radius $\epsilon$.

Comment: Ok I am picturing the interval, I am picture the balls with radius $\epsilon$, but these balls are not touching, if they were to touch, then $\epsilon$ would be 0.5 in radius, is this okay?

Comment: They are not touching but they are overlapping one another significantly, as the balls are $<\epsilon$ you cannot have them "touch" each other without overlapping.

Comment: And also wouldn't it be natural to assume that this interval would be covered by unit open sets (i.e. open segments) instead of open balls? Just to save space ;p

Comment: In general metric spaces unit open sets/intervals is equivalent to our balls :)