# Is there a name for a cover of a set $S$, where sets in $C$ contain no elements not in $S$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to construct a cover $C$ of a set $S$, such that no element of an element of $C$ is not in $S$. Equivalently, I want the union of $C$ to be identical to $S$. Is there a special name for $C$?

Thank you!

(apologies if this isn't very relevant or interesting -- I'm a philosopher, not a mathematician)

Comment: If the sets in $C$ are all distinct from each other it is called a *partition*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set If you are ok with having overlap ... then I don;lt what a general name would be .. though 'cover' sounds pretty good to me :P

Comment: if you don't want them to overlap as well you would probably call C a pairwise disjoint partition of S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mathematical name is .... [cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_(topology)) !

If you have a cover where all of the elements of $C$ share no common elements (i.e. where every element of $S$ occurs in exactly one element of $C$), then it is called a [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition).

Comment: Thanks! I was confused by [this answer](to a related question) which characterises covers such that some elements of elements of C might not be in S. But the (presumably strictly correct) definition on wikipedia doesn't allow for this.

Comment: Sorry: [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1295213/1266119)